# Search specific objects in ArrayList by attribute

Tags: java, arraylist

Good day,

Imagine I have the following code:
(These are obviously not all the attributes)

```
class Owner {
    private String name;
}

class Car {
    private Owner owner;
    private String brandName;

    public boolean isClean() { // not included in the contructor
        return false;
    }

class FuelCar extends Car {
    private String fuelType;

    public boolean isClean() {
        if (fuelType.equals("Diesel")){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
    }
}

class ElectricCar extends Car {
    private int batteryLevel;

    public boolean isClean() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The objects are added to an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
```

Examples:

```
cars.add(new Auto("Audi", new Owner("Peter")));
cars.add(new Auto("Fiat", new Owner("Rob")));
cars.add(new Auto(Mercedes, null));
cars.add(new ElectricCar(10, "Opel ", new Owner("Unknown")));
cars.add(new ElectricCar(100,"Google", new Owner("Google")));
cars.add(new FuelCar("diesel", "Seat", new Owner("Tom")));
cars.add(new FuelCar("gasonline", "Smart", new Owner("Marcel")));
```

Now the questions are:

1. How can I make a method so I only list all cars which have the value isClean "true";
2. How can I make a method with the following signature:
   public static void printCarsSpecific(ArrayList Cars, String fuelType)
   So for example if I put in:
   printCarsSpecific("gasoline");
   that only those cars will be shown when printing the ArrayList.

PS: it's not homework. Just for education
I typed the code above by myself and didnt copy and paste because it would become way to large.

I tried these methods:

```
public static void printBedrijfsautosMetType(ArrayList<Auto> autos, String brandstof) {
    Iterator<Auto> iter = autos.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Auto auto = iter.next();

        if (auto instanceof BrandstofAuto) {
            String brandstof1 = ((BrandstofAuto) auto).getBrandstof();
            if (!brandstof1.equals(brandstof) || brandstof1 == null) {
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < autos.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(autos.get(i));
        }

    }
}
```

and

```
   public static void printSchoneAutos(ArrayList<Auto> autos) {
        Iterator<Auto> iter = autos.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Auto auto = iter.next();
            if (auto instanceof BrandstofAuto) {
                boolean isschoon = ((BrandstofAuto) auto).isSchoon();
                boolean isschoon3 = auto.isSchoon();
                if (isschoon3 == false || isschoon == false) {
                    iter.remove();
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < autos.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(autos.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
```

I guess I don't have to delete these items as i've seen by examples under here.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @R.Schouten You should at least indent your codes first. Further more, your syntax is wrong and why are words like `class` and `private` in uppercase? It seems to me you don't even know the very basics. Perhaps you should post what you have tried so far.

Comment: This does seem suspiciously like a homework assignment...

Comment: @TomMorris homework assignments can be the subject of valid StackOverflow questions, provided the OP includes a summary of the work he/she has done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty he/she is having solving it.

Comment: [Don't compare strings using `==`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/4125191). And when you present "code", it should be code that compiles correctly (braces are properly closed, comments are preceded by `//` rather than `==` (in Java)), and the code should be indented properly.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, objects are passed by reference, that is `printSchoneAutos(ArrayList<Auto> autos)` will modify original collection of your cars, since autos is just reference on object that is passed to method = your cars collection. Therefore you should not delete objects in this method if you don't want to change the original collection.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a homework assignment, but I'll bite.

The simplest way is to iterate through the original list and select items from it that match.

```
ArrayList<Car> cleanCars = new ArrayList<Car>();
for (Car car : scars) {
    if (car.isClean()) {
        cleanCars.add(car);
    }
}
```

One would obviously create an object to wrap the collection of cars in. Perhaps something like `CarCollection`, which would itself wrap a collection object like `ArrayList`.

---

The second part of the question seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why would you want to mix together the logic of filtering your collection of car objects and printing them out? (Except, you know, if it is a homework assignment.) Data sorting logic and presentation logic should be separated out wherever possible.

Instead of the following:

`public static void printCarsSpecific(ArrayList Cars, String fuelType)`

Why not have a method that filters the list of cars?

`public static ArrayList<Car> getCarsByFuelType(ArrayList cars, String fuelType)`

Then when you have that filtered collection, then you can do what you want with them (i.e. print them out)?

Here's how I'd implement it. I'd have a `CarCollection` class which wraps and provides access methods you need on top of a private `ArrayList`. Like this.

```
public class CarCollection {
    private ArrayList<Car> carList;

    public void add(Car car) {
        carList.add(car);
    }

    public CarCollection getCleanCars() {
        CarCollection cleanCars = new CarCollection();
        for (Car car : this.cars) {
            if (car.isClean()) {
                cleanCars.add(car);
            }
        }
        return cleanCars;
    }

    public CarCollection getCarsByFuelType(String fuelType) {
        CarCollection filteredCars = new CarCollection();
        for (Car car : this.cars) {
            if (car instanceof FuelCar) {
                if (car.fuelType.equals(fuelType)) {
                    filteredCars.add(car);
                }
            }
        }
        return filteredCars;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard-coded filtering list of cars:

```
public static List<Car> filterCleanFuelCars(List<Car> cars) {
    List<Car> filtered = new LinkedList<>();
    for (Car c : cars) {
        if (c instanceof FuelCar) {
            FuelCar fuelCar = (FuelCar) c;
            if (fuelCar.isClean()) {
                filtered.add(fuelCar);
            }
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

Filtering list of cars based on custom condition (hard-coded condition is replaced by predicate):

```
public static List<Car> filterCars(List<Car> cars, Predicate<Car> condition) {
    List<Car> filtered = new LinkedList<>();
    for (Car c : cars) {
        if (condition.apply(c)) {
            filtered.add(c);
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

The same as above with `Stream`:

```
public static List<Car> filterCars(List<Car> cars, Predicate<Car> condition) {
    return cars.stream()
               .filter(condition)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Example of usage:

```
List<Car> cleanCars = filterCars(cars, new Predicate<Car>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Car c) {
        return c.isClean();
    }
});
```

This can be shortened via **lambda expression** (substitution for anonymous class)

```
List<Car> cleanCars = filterCars(cars, (Car c) -> c.isClean());
```

If you need more lines to decide whether the filter applies for the car, you can write:

```
List<Car> cleanFuelCars = filterCars(cars, (Car c) -> {
    if (c instanceof FuelCar) {
        FuelCar fuelCar = (FuelCar) c;
        return c.isClean();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Since not all cars contained in list extends `FuelCar`, you need to check at first, whether the car is instance of `FuelCar`, after that, you need to cast this car into `FuelCar` type and finally check value of the `fuelType` attribute.

Note, that `String` value can not be checked for equality by using `==` operator, since `String` is not *primitive data type* like `int, long, float, double` which are always **passed by value** (when you pass `int` to a method, then `int` is copied into local variable of the method - parameter). Comparing objects like `String` via `==` checks only equality of references, that is, checks if two objects are pointing to the same object in memory - objects are always **passed by references** (addresses). In short, when you work with string always use equals method.

```
public static void printCarsSpecific(List<Car> cars, String fuelType) {
    for (Car c : cars) {
        if (c instanceof FuelCar) {
            FuelCar fuelCar = (FuelCar) c;
            if (fuelCar.fuelType.equals(fuelType)) {
                System.out.println(fuelCar);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also rewrite `printCarsSpecific` to more generic method by using `filterCars` method:

```
public static void printCarsSpecific(List<Car> cars, Predicate<Car> p) {
    List<Car> filtered = filterCars(cars, p);
    for (Car c : filtered) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

To print gasoline fuel cars you would write:

```
printCarsSpecific(cars, (Car c) -> {
    if (c instanceof FuelCar) {
        FuelCar fuelCar = (FuelCar) c;
        retur fuelCar.fuelType.equals("gasoline");
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 8 you could use fancy streams such as :

```
List<Car> cleanCars = carList.stream().filter(car -> car.isClean()).collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Car> carsFilteredOnFuelType = carList.stream().filter(car -> fueltype.equals(car.fueltype)).collect(Collectors.toList));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to not declare variables as `ArrayList` if you do not need to do so. The bigger the abstraction, the more general is your code and thus the more powerful your program is. Look at this example:

```
ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
```

Why do you have to say that `cars` will be `ArrayList`? You need to specify the exact type only at instantiation. This is superior:

```
AbstractList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
```

`ArrayList` `implements` `AbstractList` and you might decide later to switch `cars` to another type of `AbstractList` implementation.

Also, read/watch some tutorials, as you are struggling even with the most basic syntax.

And now let us see your questions. Your first question asks for a way to list out only clean `cars`. This task is not atomic and you need to separate the tasks. First of all, it is nice to get the clean subset of `cars`. This type of task could be useful even if you are not intending to list them. So, let us implement it independently:

```
public static AbstractList<Car> getCleanCars(AbstractList<Car> cars) {
    AbstractList<Car> cleanCars = new ArrayList<Car>();
    for (Car car : cars) {
        if (car.isClean()) {
            cleanCars.add(car);
        }
    }
    return cleanCars;
}
```

And then you need a method which displays `cars`. Let's suppose it looks like this:

```
public static void displayCars(AbstractList<Car> cars) {
    //Display the cars
}
```

You will need to call `displayCars` like this: `Car.displayCars(Car.getCleanCars(cars))`

Your second question is illogical, since you want to call a method declared with two parameters using a single parameter. Since your code is full of errors, it is really unreadable, so I am not able to help you with that, however, if somehow a fuel type can be determined from a `Car` object, then you need to iterate the list of cars as shown above and instead of calling `isClean`, you will need to compare the fuel type of the `Car` as a `String` to the parameter you are receiving, using the `.equals()` method.